# How to change IOPS on SQL DB server

Tags: sql-server, performance

Can anyone advise please? An application I'm supporting requires IOPS on DB server to be increased during a process, in order to improve throughput and then put back to original value after the process.

Is this something to be done by the SQL DBA or the Server team? If by SQL DBA, could someone advise how to do this please, or point me to an article that **clearly** tells me what to do?

Thank you.

Comment: IOPS stands for "I/O operations per second"; it is a property of your storage subsystem, you cannot increase it on a whim. You can throttle (restrict) it at the application (SQL Server in this case) side, but in order to increase it your storage needs to be reconfigured or re-provisioned.

Comment: Thank you @AaronBertrand

Comment: @mustaccio thank you very  much, that is very helpful. So am I correct to request the storage team to have a look at the requirement, or is the change something expected of me to make?

Comment: You do need to talk to your storage/infrastructure people, but be prepared to justify your request. No matter if you're running on bare metal, virtualized hardware, or cloud, increasing storage capability is going to be associated with significant cost and, if not on cloud, also effort.

Comment: Thank you very much both (Aaron Bertrand and Mustaccio), I do appreciate your very helpful advice and guidance. Thanks again.